# How can I determine why my "AfterTest" annotation method is not working?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

As per browserclose () method, Internet Explorer should be closed at the end of the operation. But it's not closing.

Here is the code:

Multiple Test:

```
<suite name="TestingSuite">
    <test name="Tester">
        <classes>
            <class name="framework2.NewTest"/>
            <class name="framework2.NewTest2"/>
        </classes>
    </test> 
</suite>
```

NewTest.Java:

```
package framework2;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
public class NewTest {

    public WebDriver driver;
    @BeforeTest
    public void launchbrowser() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Users\\rprem\\Downloads\\IEDriverServer_x64_3.4.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        System.out.println("TestCase 0: Google was launched");
    }

    @Test
    public void OpenMail(){
        driver.get("https://www.gmail.com");
        System.out.println("Testcase 1: Gmail was launached");
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void browserclose (){
        driver.close();
        System.out.println("TestCase 2: Browser was closed");
    }
}
```

NewTest2.java:

```
package framework2;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
public class NewTest2 {
    @Test
    public void OpenYahooMail(){
        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        System.setProperty("WebDriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Users\\rprem\\Downloads\\IEDriverServer_x64_3.4.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        driver.get("https://login.yahoo.com/");
        System.out.println("Testcase2_1: Yahoo mail was launached");
    }
}
```

Logs:

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
3.4.0.0
Listening on port 2133
Only local connections are allowed
Jul 29, 2017 5:16:13 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
TestCase 0: Google was launched
Testcase 1: Gmail was launached
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
3.4.0.0
Listening on port 23709
Only local connections are allowed
Jul 29, 2017 5:16:18 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Testcase2_1: Yahoo mail was launached
TestCase 2: Browser was closed
PASSED: OpenMail
PASSED: OpenYahooMail

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What did you expect to happen, what actually happened? Did you get any error logs?

Comment: Hi Halfer, thanks for your response.                                                                                                          As per browserclose () method, internet explorer should be closed at the end of the operation. But it's not closing. That is the issue.

Comment: Would you add in a sample of your logs for when it tries to do that close? Edit your question, and use the code formatting tool please.

Comment: Halfer: Please check below logs. It's showing browserclose() is passed but it's not closing IE browser                                                                                                                                   Jul 29,2017 4:52:38 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
TestCase 0: Google was launched
Testcase 1: Gmail was launached
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
3.4.0.0
Listening on port 30442
Only local connections are allowed
Testcase2_1: Yahoo mail was lauanched
TestCase 2: Browser was closed

Comment: ^ Please [edit those logs into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45386462/edit), as I asked.

Comment: Done Halfer..check now

Comment: Please format those logs, as I asked. Select the log data, click the `{}` formatting tool icon, check they look good in the preview window, re-save.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your test code.

You have a `WebDriver` instance as a data member in the class `NewTest.java`. You are having a `driver.close()` invocation being done in the `@AfterTest` annotated `browserclose()` method.

You have another `WebDriver` instance being instantiated in the class `NewTest2.java` via the statement `WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();` but this driver is not being cleaned up by calling `driver.quit()`.

So you would need to invoke `driver.quit()` in `NewTest2.java` as well.

There are some additional issues with your test code.

- Managing the WebDriver instantiation and cleanup using a `@BeforeTest` and `@AfterTest` annotated methods is a bad idea because these methods get called only once per `<test>` tag. So if you have two or more `<class>` entries in your `<test>` tag. You should instead of using `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` to manage the same.
- For cleaning up a `WebDriver` instance, you should be invoking `driver.quit()` and not `driver.close()`